# Restart Cast custom channel on screen orientation change

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I'm using code from [Github sample project - googlecast/CastHelloText-android](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android/blob/master/src/com/example/casthelloworld/MainActivity.java) but they have hardcoded in AndroidManifest 
`android:screenOrientation="portrait"` and I want to be able to rotate screen and use split-screen (android nougat). It closes the custom channel and I cant restart it.

Comment: I'm using sender sdk v3

Answer (score 0):

Automatic reconnection is handled by the Cast SDK. You have to ensure that you call the right API to join an existing session if one already exists.